# "The recurrence format wasn't valid" error while enumerating calendar events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm using Microsoft Graph (beta) to iterate thorough master calendar events. The request is the following:

```
/beta/Users('user-id')/calendars('master-calendar-id')/events?$expand=attachments
```

To iterate, I'm using combination of top and skip parameters:

```
/beta/Users('user-id')/calendars('master-calendar-id')/events?$expand=attachments&$top=100&$skip=800
```

On some calendars I'm receiving following error:

```
ErrorCode: "ErrorInvalidOperation"

ErrorMessage:"The recurrence format wasn't valid."
```

I couldn't find any information on that kind of error, neither could I understand what event exactly is at fault.

What is that error, what should I do with it?

Comment: Do you care about retrieving recurrence pattern? One option might be to simply _not_ request that property.

Comment: As for diagnosing, you could set your `$top` to 1 and have your code iterates through a failing calendar until it fails. Based on the last calendar item you were able to receive, you should be able to narrow down which event is failing. I'd also suggest trying against the v1.0 endpoint just to make sure this isn't a beta issue.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur thank you for both comments. I'm not sure if I need recurrence pattern, I'll check if it'll work without it. The narrowing down isn't applicable because I don't have user (delegated) access to the tenant, I have an application access only. But I'll try v1.0 instead.

Comment: I'm not sure how the scope type fits in here. The purpose of narrowing down to the event that is failing is to give you a "known bad" example so you can understand what about the data is triggering an exception.

Answer (score 0):

> The recurrence format wasn't valid.

This seems some issue on your recurring events.

You need to check if all your event are in [right format](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/outlook-schedule-recurring-events). If you use **calendars('master-calendar-id')/events**, not all the events are being listed for the upcoming weeks and those are the recurring events.

And if you're going to be analyzing calendars, you should use the [/calendarView](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview) endpoint. This gives you a "rendered" view of the calendar for a given date range.  not all the events are being listed for the upcoming weeks and I suppose those are the recurring events.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<meeting room email>/calendarView/?endDateTime=2018-8-1T22:23:00Z&startDateTime=2018-9-28T00:00:00Z
```

Comment: Thank you for calendar view endpoint. I'll try it. I doubt that it will work with invalid recurrence format though. The problem is that I don't have permissions to modify events. I could skip it, but I don't know what to skip because I can't get the event itself..